# Javascript JQuery toggle nested elements with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, toggle

I am currently having trouble accessing my list subclass. The idea is to create multi-level unfolding list with check boxes working as buttons. Right now it all folds/unfolds at the same time and we want elements to unfold by checking/unchecking it's parent.

I do realise I can use less/sass to hide/show those elements by clicking on them, but I would like to learn how do do it with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

 $('.sub-ul').hide();
  
 $('.side-checkbox').each(function () {
    var obj = $('.sub-ul');
    $(this).click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        obj.show(300);
      } else {
        obj.hide(200);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul-nav">
  <li class="li-nav">
  
    <a class="side-menu-checkbox" href="#">(A)Lorem</a>

    <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" class="side-checkbox">

    <ul class="ul-nav sub-ul">
      <li class="li-nav">
        <a href="#">(B)Ipsum</a>

        <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="b" class="side-checkbox">

        <ul class="ul-list sub-ul">
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="side-menu-plus">(B)Ipsum</a>

        <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="c" class="side-checkbox">

        <ul class="ul-list sub-ul">
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(A)Lorem</a></li>
  <li class="li-nav">
    <a class="side-menu-checkbox" href="#">(A)Lorem</a>

    <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" class="side-checkbox">

    <ul class="ul-nav sub-ul">
      <li class="li-nav">
        <a href="#">(B)Ipsum</a>

        <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="b" class="side-checkbox">
        
        <ul class="ul-list sub-ul">
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="side-menu-plus">(B)Ipsum</a>

        <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="c" class="side-checkbox">
        

        <ul class="ul-list sub-ul">
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(A)Lorem</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer is a simple adjustment of

```
var obj = $('+ .sub-ul', this);  // Old code $('sub-ul');
```

This is a short-hand way of selecting the correct `sub-ul` list instance in your heirachy that is to be toggled for display, based on the adjacent checkbox that has been clicked.

In effect, what this change is doing is along the lines of saying:

> for the current `.side-checkbox` that is clicked (ie `this`), select the `.sub-ul` sibling that directly follows this `.side-checkbox`

Here is a working code snippet - hope this helps!

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

 $('.sub-ul').hide();
  
 $('.side-checkbox').each(function () {

    /* UPDATE: Here is the line that you need to update */
    var obj = $('+ .sub-ul', this);

    $(this).click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        obj.show(300);
      } else {
        obj.hide(200);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul-nav">
  <li class="li-nav">
  
    <a class="side-menu-checkbox" href="#">(A)Lorem</a>

    <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" class="side-checkbox">

    <ul class="ul-nav sub-ul">
      <li class="li-nav">
        <a href="#">(B)Ipsum</a>

        <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="b" class="side-checkbox">

        <ul class="ul-list sub-ul">
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="side-menu-plus">(B)Ipsum</a>

        <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="c" class="side-checkbox">

        <ul class="ul-list sub-ul">
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(A)Lorem</a></li>
  <li class="li-nav">
    <a class="side-menu-checkbox" href="#">(A)Lorem</a>

    <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" class="side-checkbox">

    <ul class="ul-nav sub-ul">
      <li class="li-nav">
        <a href="#">(B)Ipsum</a>

        <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="b" class="side-checkbox">
        
        <ul class="ul-list sub-ul">
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="side-menu-plus">(B)Ipsum</a>

        <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="c" class="side-checkbox">
        

        <ul class="ul-list sub-ul">
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
          <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(C)Dolorem</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="li-nav"><a href="#">(A)Lorem</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks you so very much! This helps a ton! <3